# RecyclerView: setOnClickListener not accessing full CardView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onitemclicklistener

I have a CardView containing an ImageView. 
Now I have implemented a onItemClickListener. 
But it is only working if I click on space of the CardView that is not covered by the image view. 
If I click on the image view there happens nothing.

How can I achieve that the CardView's onItemClick method is called even if I click on the ImageView ?

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_view_maschine"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_album_radius">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/maschine_cover_height"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/maschine_title_padding"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/maschine_title_padding"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/maschine_title_padding"
                    android:textColor="@color/recyclerViewTitleColor"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/maschine_title" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/description"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/title"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/description_count_padding_bottom"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/maschine_title_padding"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/maschine_title_padding"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/description_count" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/overflow"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/ic_maschine_overflow_width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/ic_maschine_overflow_height"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ic_maschine_overflow_margin_top"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_dots" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

OnItemClick:

```
ItemClickSupport.addTo(recyclerView).setOnItemClickListener(new ItemClickSupport.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {
                showDetailFragment();
            }
        });
```

I have used that [ItemClickSupport class](http://www.littlerobots.nl/blog/Handle-Android-RecyclerView-Clicks/).

Comment: perform cardview's click event inside your adapter.

Comment: If you don't want imageview to be clickabke then set it's android:clickable attribute to false. It's true right now that's why it's receiving touch events.

Comment: @TalhaMir setting the attribute to false did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

add the below class

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener  {

private OnItemClickListener mListener;

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}

GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
    View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

}
```

}

and you can use it for entire application as following

```
 recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            //your code here
        }
    }) );
```

Hope this work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

define interface in your adapter, something like

```
private ClickListener mClickListener;


public interface ClickListener{
    void itemClicked(View view, int position);
}
```

make public setter:

```
public void setClickListener(ClickListener clickListener){
    this.mClickListener = clickListener;
}
```

then in your viewholder:

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
     if(mClickListener!=null){
         mClickListener.mainMenuItemClicked(v, getAdapterPosition());
     }
 }
```

then in your activity on adapter:

```
adapter.setClickListener(this);

//and implement this interface

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements YourAdapter.ClickListener

@Override
public void itemClicked(View view, int position) {
}
```

if you want to catch click on image then set tag to this view and in activity you can get tag from view and see where clicked:

```
imageView.setTag("image");
imageView.setOnClickListener(this);

@Override
public void itemClicked(View view, int position) {
    if (view.getTag() != null && ((String)view.getTag()).equals("image")){
        //....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all your content within a `FrameLayout` and move the `onClickListener` to the `FrameLayout` and set `clickable` on `true`.

Example: So if your current layout looks something like this:

```
    <LinearLayout>
        <TextView/>
        <ImageView/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Wrap the content with a `FrameLayout` like this:

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        ... >

        <LinearLayout>
            <TextView/>
            <ImageView/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
```

And then move the current `onClickListener` you have to the `FrameLayout`.

PS: the foreground `android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` adds a nice ripple effect to your clickable area, this is optional.